# Detect a phrase using OpenCV and Tesseract

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using opencv and tesseract to read PDFs and detect certain words and highlight them. It works well for single words. But how can I match a specific phrase like "Hello world" and have one rectangle drawn around both words? My working code is below for reference.

```
pattern = '^\W*(match)\W*'

for i, word in enumerate(image_data['text']):
    if re.match(pattern, image_data['text'][i]):
        x,y,w,h = image_data['left'][i],image_data['top'][i],image_data['width'][i],image_data['height'][i]
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
        cv2.imwrite("new.jpg", img)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get the OCR output as a data frame, you will notice that the hierarchy of the text is available. It's in form paragraph number, line number, word number, etc. Start when the word number is 0 and combine the number of words you want to detect. Then, use the left and top of the first one and the left and width of the second one to draw the rectangle.